# Slanted element in 3D space with CSS3

Tags: html, css, shapes

I'd like to make this slanted / rotated element with CSS3.

[image]

I've tried with `clip-path` but after the shape is created I can't add border, box-shadow or border-radius to it.

```
clip-path: polygon(5% 7%, 98% 0, 100% 83%, 0 74%);
```

I've tried with `transform` but this is not only rotated, because the sides have different orientation. Also I've tried with **SVG**, but information that I've found was insufficient for me to find a solution to my problem. This is my last solution, I'd rather use CSS3 than SVG, if possible...
Any sugestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use CSS3 [`rotate3d`<sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate3d)

- `perspective` on a parent element
- `transform: rotate3d(x, y, z, a)` on it's child

```css
/*QuickReset*/ *{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;} html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}
body{background: #2C8BF9;}



.slantedParent{
  position:relative;
  width: 300px; height:200px;
  top:10px; left:10px;
  
  perspective: 800px;
}


.slanted{
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 32px;
  height:100%;
  padding: 32px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  
  transform: rotate3d(3, -2, 0.4, 25deg); /* play with those values */
}
```

```html
<div class="slantedParent">
  <div class="slanted">
    <h1>Some content?</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this.

```css
#shape {
   box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 150px;
 height: 100px;
 -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-10deg);
      -o-transform: skew(-10deg);
 background: red;
  border-radius:5px;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;
 border: 5px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="shape"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But my margins are not parallel, they have different sloping in all coordinates (north, south ...). My object is not parallelogram.

Comment: Then you go with a rotate property of CSS.